# MySQLdb for python behaves differently for queries than the mysql workbench browser

Tags: python, mysql

I am executing update in mysqldb which is changing the values of part of a key and field.  When I execute the query in python it triggers something in the database to cause it to add extra rows. When I execute the same exact query from mysql workbench it performs the update correctly without adding extra rows.  What is the difference between calling from the application and calling from python?

Thanks

Comment: Code please? Without code, it is difficult to visualize what could be wrong.

Comment: Are you committing the transaction?

Answer (score 0):

There was a trigger activating that I did not know about. Thanks for the help